# Why find_child_elements ignores first parameter in Perl Selenium?

Tags: perl, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Using perl 5.22, and Selenium::Remote::WebElement::VERSION = '0.2701' on OSX and Firefox. Trying to use Selenium for the first time (and XPath too!).

My problem arises when I try to get a given "< select >" child and then enumerate all its "< option ">s as thus:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Selenium::Remote::Driver;
use Selenium::Remote::WebElement;
use URI::file;

my $extraCaps = {"browser" => "Firefox", "browser_version" => "42.0","os" => "OSX","os_version" => "7","resolution" => "1024x768"};

my $driver = new Selenium::Remote::Driver('remote_server_addr' => 'localhost', 'port' => '4444','extra_capabilities' => $extraCaps);
$driver->get(URI::file->new_abs('./test.html')->as_string);
sleep(2);
# get <select> named 'SEL2':
my $sel2 = $driver->find_element('//select[@name="SEL2"]');
# this works, but it's not what i want: my $sel2_options = $driver->find_child_elements($sel2, '//select[@name="SEL2"]//option');
# get all the options for **that specific** <select>
my $sel2_options = $driver->find_child_elements($sel2, '//option');
foreach my $ap (@$sel2_options){
    print "found option ".$ap->get_text()."\n";
}
sleep(1);
$driver->quit();
```

The input html file (test.html) is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head></head>
<body>
<select name="SEL1" id="ID1">
    <option value="SEL1-option11">SEL1-option1</option>
    <option value="SEL1-option12">SEL1-option2</option>
    <option value="SEL1-option13">SEL1-option3</option>
</select>
<select name="SEL2" id="ID2">
    <option value="SEL2-option1">SEL2-option1</option>
    <option value="SEL2-option2">SEL2-option2</option>
    <option value="SEL2-option3">SEL2-option2</option>
</select>
</body></html>
```

And the output I get is:

```
found option SEL1-option1
found option SEL1-option2
found option SEL1-option3
found option SEL2-option1
found option SEL2-option2
found option SEL2-option2
```

Shouldn't I get *only* the options for SEL2 listed?

Am I doing something wrong? It seems to me that for this case, find_child_elements ignores its first parameter which is - as i understand it - the WebElement to apply the specified selector (//option) to it.

On the other hand this works as expected, but it somehow defies the purpose:

```
my $sel2_options = $driver->find_child_elements($sel2, '//select[@name="SEL2"]//option');
```

many thanks,
bliako

Comment: try `my $sel2_options = $sel2->find_elements('//option');`

Comment: nope, in my system, there is no method 'find_elements' in sel2 (Selenium::Remote::WebElement)

Comment: I suspect problem is with `$sel2` (maybe it's null?). Don't you need to escape `@` in xpath, i.e.: `my $sel2 = $driver->find_element('//select[\@name="SEL2"]');`? Example says so at least: http://search.cpan.org/~chowes/Selenium-Remote-Driver-0.17/lib/Selenium/Remote/Driver.pm#find_child_elements

Comment: just for the record, escape the `@` when inside double-quotes and will be interpolated by perl. When inside single quotes like above, no need to escape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/` at the beginning of an XPath always references document's root node. That's why you got all `option` elements instead of `option`s from `$sel2` only. Try adding a `.` at the beginning of the XPath to make it relative to current element context :

```
my $sel2_options = $driver->find_child_elements($sel2, './/option');
```

Comment: Please downvote me! There is an example right in CPAN documentation Kiril S. had cited for `find_child_element()` and I have read and re-read: Usage: `my $elem1 = $driver->find_element("//select[\@name='ned']");` `# note the usage of ./ when searching for a child element instead of //` `my $child = $driver->find_child_element($elem1, "./option[\@value='es_ar']");` However the example in the same document, section of `find_child_elements()` says thus: `Usage: my $elem1 = $driver->find_element("//select[\@name='ned']"); my $child = $driver->find_child_elements($elem1, "//option");`

Comment: ... needless to say I followed the example in section find_child_elements() instead. Just to share my experience so far with Selenium (which is cool tool): I found it very useful to add a SIG handler to quit selenium client in case of a ctrl-C or a die(), otherwise it remains running in the background, notice the `__DIE__` handler for each die() Selenium is throwing:` $SIG{INT} = $SIG{HUP} = $SIG{``__DIE__``} = $SIG{TERM} = (sub{$selenium->quit});` Thanks for your help.